# Password hash returning false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I have a simple login script, but when I started encrypting passwords and using `password_verify` I seem to get the same result all the time, `false`. Here's my login script

```
<?php

session_start();

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$dbname = "users";

try{
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);    
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');


 $st = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :pass");
 $st->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->execute();

$rows = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

if($email === ''){
$_SESSION['message1'] = 'Enter a valid email';
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}
elseif($pass === ''){
$_SESSION['message1'] = 'Enter a valid password';
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}
elseif($rows > 0){
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
$hash = $con->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = :email");
$hash->bindValue(':email', $email);
$hash->execute();

}
elseif(password_verify($pass, $hash)){
    $name = $con->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = :email");
    $name->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $name->execute();
    $rows = $name->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
         $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    }
    header('Location: profile.php');
     }
else{
    $_SESSION['message1'] = 'Make sure email and password are correct';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
 ?>
```

Also here's how I'm encrypting

```
    $passh = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
    $db = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (:name, :email, :passh)");
    $db->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':passh', $passh, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->execute();
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    header('Location: profile.php');
    exit();
```

Error reporting is enabled, but for some reason its still not working and simply displays `Make sure email and password are correct`, which come from the next else statement. Any ideas? I'm fairly new. Also any security tips would be great. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    <?php

session_start();

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$passw = "root";
$dbname = "users";

try{
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $passw);   
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');



$hash = $con->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = :email");
$hash->bindValue(':email', $email);
$hash->execute();
$rows1 = $hash->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows1 as $row1) {
     $_SESSION['hash'] = $row1['hash'];
     }



$st = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :pass");
$st->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->execute();

$rows = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

if($email === ''){
    $_SESSION['message1'] = 'Enter a valid email';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
elseif($pass === ''){
    $_SESSION['message1'] = 'Enter a valid password';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
elseif($rows > 0 || password_verify($pass, $hash) ){
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $name = $con->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = :email");
    $name->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $name->execute();
    $rows = $name->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
         $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    }
    header('Location: profile.php');
    }
else{
    $_SESSION['message1'] = 'Make sure email and password are correct';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56296/discussion-between-user302975-and-rocket-hazmat).

Comment: @user302975: No matter what you do, `$hash` is *still* not a string.  It's the SQL statement.  You want `password_verify($pass, $_SESSION['hash'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your query one more time:

```
SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = :email
```

You are selecting the column password,

when you fetch the row you are using the field `hash`

```
$_SESSION['hash'] = $row1['hash'];
```

Unlike you think, your script is not simple at all, you are performing 3 queries on the same record, try this approach

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

if($email === ''){
    $_SESSION['message1'] = 'Enter a valid email';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

if($pass === ''){
    $_SESSION['message1'] = 'Enter a valid password';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

$query = 'SELECT name, email, password 
          FROM users 
          WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1';


$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!$row){
    $_SESSION['message1'] = 'User does not exist';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

//hashed password from Database
$hash = $row['password'];

if(password_verify($pass, $hash)){
    $_SESSION['hash'] = $row['password'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    header('Location: profile.php');
}else{
    $_SESSION['message1'] = 'Make sure email and password are correct';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```