# Can't get username in URL

Tags: php, mysql, database, url, pdo

So I'm trying to make public profiles. So i'm getting the result from the database and shooting it back. Here's my code

```
$username = $con->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE email=:email");
$username->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$username->execute();
$userurl = $_GET['username'];
```

For some reason I'm not getting anything back. No errors either. Any help would be great. So basically what I want to do is get `example.com/profile?username=joe`

Comment: Is that all the code you are running? You do nothing with the result from the database.

Comment: Don't I set it as a url with `GET`? or is there another way to do this @Rangad

Comment: You don't set anything with `$_GET`. It is used to read query params from the current request. If you want to build a url you have to do it yourself.

Comment: `$_GET` doesn't fetch results from a database operation, it fetches values from the URL query string.  You don't seem to be fetching any results from your database query, just executing it and ignoring it.

Comment: So how would I take the user to the user profile? I'd get a username, then what? @David

Comment: @user302975: Define "take the user to the user profile" first.  What specifically are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to build a URL and direct the user to that URL?  In that case you'd get the username from the database query and construct the string of the URL and then use a Location header: `header('Location: ' . $someUrl);`  You wouldn't use `$_GET` anywhere in that operation.

Comment: Sorry for being broad. So what I want to do is have the user enter a URL, such as `example.com/profile.php?username=joe`. Then when they go to that page I want the username to be displayed. Just so that then I know its working. Would I do `echo $username` on the page? @David

Comment: @user302975: Based on that description it doesn't sound like a database would even be involved.  If `profile.php` just needs to echo what's in the `username` value in the query string then it would just do something like: `echo $_GET['username'];`  Note that you should use `isset()` first to determine if a `username` value was provided.  Also, technically this is a potential avenue of attack so you want to HTML-encode the query string value (not sure how to do that in PHP, look it up).

Comment: First of all thanks for terrific responses. Well I want to display more data then just the username, but I would want to pull it _out_ of a database. @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE email=:email");
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch();
$username = $row['username'];


$userurl = "example.com/profile?username=$username";
header("Location: $userurl") ;
```

You executed the query but never fetched the data, `$_GET` doesn't do what you think, it is meant to get a query string value.

As the @Rangad and @David pointed out in the comment below, you should generate the query string using [**http_build_query**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
...
$stmt->execute(); 
$row = $stmt->fetch();
header('Location: example.com/profile?'.http_build_query($row)) ;
```

Comment: So If a user was to enter a username it would basically take them to a user profile? Then how would I display a username for example to test if this really work?

Comment: Nitpicking, but you should handle $username according to it's context. It may contain anything. Consider using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: @user302975 this will redirect user to profile page based on the username.

Comment: @Rangad what do you mean? username comes from the db

Comment: Well I guess my real question is _how_ do I generate the page? `echo $username`?

Comment: @meda: Yes, it comes from the database, but it's still just a string which was originally supplied by a user.  It can contain *anything*.  It's important to do things like URL-encode string values.

Comment: You have a valid point, but I never used it, can you please included it in my post? is it `$userurl = "example.com/profile?".http_build_query(row);`

Comment: @meda I'd use that to display the username in the page? ^^

Comment: @user302975 yes you can use $_GET on that page to get the username

Comment: Just one more question. Say I wanted to display something like the email, which is stored in the DB. How would I Do so?

Comment: @user302975 `SELECT username, email ....` but consider using session, you dont want sensitive data in query strings, I also answered your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415565/password-hash-returning-false)

Comment: Wait. Now for some reason it isn't working. Its says its a direct loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56300/discussion-between-user302975-and-meda).